# INSERT INTO and JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a question about an sql insert query using joins.

```
My database:
(tblComputer --> columns: ID - Name - Color - CPU_id - GPU_id)
(tblCPU --> columns: ID - Name)
(tblGPU --> columns: ID - Name)


Output for the query:
(tblComputer --> columns: ID: 6 - Name: HP - Color: Black - CPU_id: 1 - GPU_id: 1)
(tblCPU --> columns: ID: 1 - Name: Intel i5)
(tblGPU --> columns: ID: 1 - Name: Nvidia)
```

I want when I insert for example a computer with the name HP and color black and an intel i5 cpu and a nvidia GPU. That the CPU and GPU will be inserted into the tables tblCPU and tblGPU and that their ID's will be inserted into the columns CPU_id and GPU_id in the table tblComputer.

I hope you can understand my question!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the gquestion?

Comment: What you want is a trigger. Check this link for [Triigers in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html)

Comment: @DanielA.White My question is how I can create such a query that inserts the CPU and GPU information into their tables and the ID of the CPU en GPU into the main computer table?

Comment: Have you tried inserting into tblCPU and tblGPU first and getting their identities. Then inserting into tbComputer?

Comment: Maybe using stored procedures is what you need. I do not know why you need to do it in a single query. See this link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

Comment: It could be achieved by a trigger, but are you sure, that you want to do it on the database level? The application should be aware of what data is stored where => it should check, whether "Nvidia" and "Intel i5" are in respective tables, and if not, insert them. Then, you will have their ID and will be able to strore it in tblComputer, where the ID is a foreign key...